# Qual é o problema em usar reinterpret_cast em C++?

Tags: c++, cast

Eu sei que usar `reinterpret_cast` pode causar comportamente indefinido, mas ainda não entendi o porquê (sei que tem algo a ver com o ciclo de vida do objeto e alinhamento da memória). Gostaria de ver algum exemplo prático em que o cast resultaria em comportamento indefinido.

Answer (score 0):

Com ele você pode converter um ponteiro de qualquer tipo para qualquer outro tipo, é semelhante ao cast do C normal, aquele com (parenteses*).

O principal problema dele(s) é que o compilador não tem como verificar se a conversão faz sentido. Fica por conta e risco do desenvolvedor, e é muito fácil cometer um erro.

Por exemplo, converter um ponteiro para inteiro (int ou long int), e depois de volta para ponteiro, pode gerar comportamento indefinido. Isto funciona em muitas arquiteturas, mas não em todas. Há arquiteturas de 32 bits com ponteiros de 64 bits, int tem 32 bits no Linux 64 bits, e assim por diante.

Converter um ponteiro char* para double* é comportamento indefinido. Funciona em arquiteturas onde um double (64 bits ou 8 bytes) pode ocupar qualquer endereço de memória, mas muitas arquiteturas fazem questão que double* aponte para um múltiplo de 8. (Uma forma correta de acessar um double desalinhado é copiá-lo para uma variável local usando memcpy(), e aí usar a variável double local.)

Em algumas arquiteturas, ponteiros podem ter tamanhos diferentes de acordo com o tipo que apontam, aí pode dar bolo converter de Tipo* para void* e de volta para Tipo*.